# Update sql not working for GET variable for PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to pass a variable id (primary key in meeting table) from viewMeeting.php to modifyMeeting.php

Under viewMeeting.php:

```
<a href="modifyfinalmeeting.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $nameMeeting; ?></a>
```

Eg of URL:  http://localhost/MyProject/modifyMeeting.php?id=1

Under modifyMeeting.php:

```
//get ID from URL 
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id =$_GET['id'];
}

if (isset($_POST['updatebtn'])) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE meeting SET nameMeeting = ?, venue = ? WHERE id = ?';
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $nameMeeting, $venue, $id);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {

                //Alert to redirect
                 echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                 window.alert('Succesfully Updated')
                 window.location.href='viewfinalmeeting.php';
                 </SCRIPT>");
             } else {
                 echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
             }
        }
}

<button type="submit" name="updatebtn" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
```

If i hardcode the variable for $id (eg: $id = 2), it will update the database.

However, currently it will show "Successful Updated" but not update the database to the corresponding $id from the GET variable.

I also tried the following method but it does not work as it shows undefined function:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])
```

Please, any help as to how to update the database will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: displaying your code in  http://localhost/MyProject/modifyMeeting.php?id=1

Comment: Where are you setting the values of $nameMeeting and $venue?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: It is set within the updatebtn, i removed it here for abbreviation sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

You are submitting the form from modifyMeeting.php page, so when it will go to the target page as mentioned in the  tag it will not retain the $_GET['id'] variable as it will not be in the URL anymore.
So your database will show value "undefined" for that id.

**Solution**

When you create the form on modifyMeeting.page, set the URL to contain the GET variable

Example

```
<form action="sample.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="post">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think mixing POST and GET can sometimes be confusing. The following should work.

/updateMeeting.php

```
<form method="post" action="updateMeeting.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>">
    <button type="submit" name="updatebtn" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: this worked too! same solution as suggested. just that its "modifyMeeting.php" and not "updateMeeting.php". Thanks!